# serial.c - How do register variables in SerialState get mapped to guest memory?

Tags: serial-port, emulation, qemu

I'm currently diagnosing an issue where my guest is attempting to poll the LSR for the THRE to clear so that it can output to a UART device. However, the LSR is never updated and therefore it polls indefinitely. I'm using `serial_mm_init()` on my lightly-customized mipssim board.

I'm trying to trace through the source to find where the LSR is supposed to be updated, but all I see pertaining to that register is `uint8_t lsr` in the `SerialState` struct; I can't find anything that maps that variable to guest memory.

Could someone explain how `SerialState`'s values are mapped to guest memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of hard work I got the UART working. The answer to the question lies within the `serial_ioport_read()` and `serial_ioport_write()` functions. These two methods are assigned as the callbacks QEMU invokes when data is read or written to the `MemoryRegion` for the serial device (which is initialized in `serial_init()` or `serial_mm_init()`). These functions do a bit of masking on the address (passed into the functions as `addr`) to determine which register is being referenced, then return the value from the `SerialState` struct corresponding to that register. It's surprisingly simple, but I guess everything seems simple once you've figured it out. The big turning point was the realization that QEMU effectively implements the serial device as a `MemoryRegion` with special functionality that is triggered on a memory operation.

Anyway, hope this helps someone in the future avoid the nightmare I went through. Cheers!